# Using Map in Java. How to not overwrite Value?

Tags: java

```
    for(int i = 0; i < Board.NUM_OF_ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < Board.NUM_OF_COLS; j++) {
            if(piece.canMove(board, piece.getX(), piece.getY(), i, j)) {
                mappedPosition.put(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this code, I am trying to add a pair of (x,y) coordinate of a movable Position of a chess "piece".

For example, I was expecting it to add [2,2], [2,4], [3,1], [3,5], [5,1], [5,5], [6,2], [6,4]

But when I use put, it overwrites the Value when it has the same Key. So [2,2] just becomes [2,4] eventually.

How can I get the full list of the pair without overwriting it?

Comment: not using a map. either create a POJO or use `java.awt.Point` to store x/y coordinates. and create a list of there objects

Comment: That is what a map is - way of linking each key to a value (not multiple values). If you just want to store a list of positions, use some kind of position class and store instances in a list.

Comment: Using a map you can't do that.

Comment: See the MultiMap: https://dzone.com/articles/multimaps-google-guava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` uses the unique key identifiers thus it's impossible to have the same key twice and more.

Create the class holding the two coordinate values you need.

```
public class BoardPoint {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public BoardPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

The class above will be useful in case you need to scale: implement more variables or perform some operations over the pair of values. If you need just a POJO (plain-old Java object) the class `java.awt.Point` should be enough as @XtremeBaumer said id the comments.

Comment: Don't forget to implement equals() and hashcode () methods, as well as make the class immutable, if you want to use the instances of the class as keys in map.

Answer (score 0):

Map by definition is key --> value. And each key can only have one value at each moment. You can either use set when the values are pair of (x,y) or just a list, it depends on how you wish to use this information later.

Answer (score 0):

You can, use Guava's Multimap.

```
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put(1, "rohit");
multimap.put(1, "jain");

System.out.println(multimap.get(1));  // Prints - [rohit, jain]
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can also use a Multimap. The API is similar, but the value is always a Collection.

http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache MultiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) for holding several values per key

> MultiMap mhm = new MultiValueMap();
> mhm.put(key, "A");
> mhm.put(key,
> "B");
> mhm.put(key, "C");
> Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
>
> coll will be a collection containing "A", "B", "C".